# Expression not working in a child group

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, parent-child, query-expressions

I have made a report that has a parent group fully working with expression. I have also for a child group that is visible once selected the toggle.

But I'm struggle to get the expression working in the child group when the parent works fine . Results are just showing as rows and rows of zero . When In fact I'm after a single count.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the expression that is giving the problem

Answer (score 0):

If you want the same count. You need to specify the scope of the parent group.

```
=COUNT(Fields!xyz.Value, "ParentGroup")
```

Comment: =sum(iif(fields!misc.value = "imported",1,0))

Comment: But I want to add an extra value in there to break it down

Comment: what do you mean by break it down? Edit your question to include an example of the expected results. Also additional details about your data would be useful.

Comment: My first expression gives me a total count of 4665 (which is total leads imported for my above expression. So when I hit the toggle I want to break down on what source. I now want to use an expression in the below box on the line of    =sum(iif(fields!misc.value = "imported" ,1,0) and fields!.leadsource.value = "A") I can then report that for my expressions

Comment: @S.Parky If your groups are defined correctly then you can directly use this expression `=sum(iif(fields!misc.value = "imported" ,1,0))` no need to filter by leadsource as group will take care of it.